# Maths Notation in Andrew Ng's CS229 course online

Tags: notation, mathematical-statistics

I have just started Andrew Ng's Machine Learning course of which a legacy version is online. Here are the notes I am using, it is lecture two of the series on youtube too:

https://see.stanford.edu/materials/aimlcs229/cs229-notes1.pdf (around page 5)

[image]

He derives an equation for LMS/ gradient descent. I thought I understood the derivation until the $x^{(i)}_j$ (raised i, lowered j) I do not understand what this means! I thought it was perhaps a matrix index but that would be both lowered, it is to do with the summation and the iteration separately, I believe, but do not understand what this would represent (is the last $x$ on the right meaning $x_1, x_2,\dots, x_n$ summed but then what is the $j$?). A simple example would help! If anyone could help out that would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it abundantly clear (I took the same course), Andrew Ng's notation uses superscripts to index [**examples**](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/193925/67822), and subscripts to denote **features**.

Hence, if we are looking at some botanical study, and collect data on a grove of trees, the tree labeled $\text{number } 25$ would be an example in the training data, and the features measured on the tree would be expressed as a vector of the form:

$$\small x^{(25)}=\left( x^{(25)}_1, x^{(25)}_2,\dots,x^{(25)}_n \right)=\small\left(x^{(25)}_1 = \text{height}; \,x^{(25)}_2 = \text{crown diameter};\,\dots, \,x^{(25)}_n=\text{trunk diameter}\right)$$

So the updating sums over each $i$ examples (subjects if you imagine a medical study), *simultaneously for every $j$* (for every feature).

Notice that in calculating the gradient, we obtain partial derivatives of a quadratic, $(h_\theta(x)-y)^2$ form, such as the $\color{blue}{2}(h_\theta(x)-y)$ will cancel out with a $\frac{1}{2}$ inserted in the $J(\theta)$ formula for this purpose.

When you apply the chain rule, you end up getting the partial of inside of the parenthesis $h_\theta(x)-y$ for every feature $j$, running into the "unfolding" of $h_\theta(x)$, which, for the tree in the example above, is really the dot product of the vector $x^{(25)}$ ("for all $j$) with the vector of weights as they are at any particular iteration. However, $h_\theta(x)$ updates factoring the input from all the examples (subjects or trees).

Answer (score 1):

$x_i^{(j)}$ designates the value of the $i^{\text {th}}$ feature of the $j^ {\text {th}}$ sample in the training set.